# Reactive text in Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to get two text fields to display based on a reactive user defined ID. However, what I have currently is not displaying any text for the desired fields. I thought it had to do with the fact that there are 25 data points with the same ID_no (I am using the data to plot, but since it was unrelated to my question, I removed the plot). However, after removing the data in troubleshooting, no text was being displayed still. I am pretty sure my error is in lines 51 and 52 of the code, but I am unsure how to correct it.  Any help with troubleshooting is appreciated.

```
#Check packages to use in library
{
  library('shiny') #allows for the shiny app to be used
  library('magrittr')
}

#Data

ID_no <- 123
Data_val <- sample(0:100, 25)
employee_name <- as.character("Employee1")
date <- Sys.Date()
ID_1 <-data.frame(ID_no, Data_val, employee_name, date)

ID_no <- 456
Data_val <- sample(0:100, 25)
employee_name <- as.character("Employee2")
date <- Sys.Date()-10
ID_2 <-data.frame(ID_no, Data_val, employee_name, date)

data <-rbind(ID_1, ID_2)
IDchoices <- as.character(unique(data$ID_no))

# UI

  ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(4,
             wellPanel(
              selectInput(inputId = "ID", label="Select ID:", choices = IDchoices, selected = "1", multiple = FALSE, selectize = TRUE)
            ),
             wellPanel(span(h5(strong("Employee:")), h5(textOutput("Staff_name"))),
                       span(h5(strong("Date:")),h5(textOutput("Date"))))
     )
    )
   )

#SERVER

server <- function(input, output, session)
{
 filteredData <- reactive({
    m <- data %>% filter(
      ID_no %in% input$ID
    )
    m
  })


 output$Staff_name <- renderText({ filteredData()$employee_name })
 output$Date <- renderText({ filteredData()$date })
}

#Run the Shiny App to Display Webpage

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: Are you using `stats::filter` or `dplyr::filter` in the reactive part on the server side? If you're using `stats::filter` you get an object of the class `mts` and then subsetting with ...()$Date won't work. If you're using `dplyr::filter` to get the subset, you should change `renderText({ filteredData()$Date })` to renderText({ filteredData()$date }).

Comment: In your dataset there is no variable called `Date` but `date`

Comment: @MichalMajka My apologies, this typo has been corrected, but did not fix the original issue.  I am using the dplyr package for the filter.

Comment: You should also attach `dplyr` package or write explicitly `dplyr::filter`. If you don't do this then shiny will use `stats::filter` function. `dplyr` will automatically import pipes from `magrittr` package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of typos where you were trying to access column name `Date` instead of `date` and `output$staff_name` instead of `output$Staff_name`
Also the `filter` function used like mentioned in the comments is from the wrong package. Either you need to specify `dplyr::filter` or load the `dplyr` library before running this code.

This should work for you:

```
  output$Staff_name <- renderText({ as.character(filteredData()$employee_name[1])})
  output$Date <- renderText({ format(filteredData()$date[1],"%Y-%m-%d") })
```

This is the entire code that works for me:

```
#Check packages to use in library
{
  library('shiny') #allows for the shiny app to be used
  library('magrittr')
}

#Data

ID_no <- 123
Data_val <- sample(0:100, 25)
employee_name <- as.character("Employee1")
date <- Sys.Date()
ID_1 <-data.frame(ID_no, Data_val, employee_name, date)

ID_no <- 456
Data_val <- sample(0:100, 25)
employee_name <- as.character("Employee2")
date <- Sys.Date()-10
ID_2 <-data.frame(ID_no, Data_val, employee_name, date)

data <-rbind(ID_1, ID_2)
IDchoices <- as.character(unique(data$ID_no))

# UI

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(4,
           wellPanel(
             selectInput(inputId = "ID", label="Select ID:", choices = IDchoices, selected = "1", multiple = FALSE, selectize = TRUE)
           ),
           wellPanel(span(h5(strong("Employee:")), h5(textOutput("Staff_name"))),
                     span(h5(strong("Date:")),h5(textOutput("Date"))))
    )
  )
)

#SERVER

server <- function(input, output, session)
{
  filteredData <- reactive({
    m <- data %>% dplyr::filter(
      ID_no %in% input$ID
    )
    m
  })


  output$Staff_name <- renderText({ as.character(filteredData()$employee_name[1]) })
  output$Date <- renderText({ format(filteredData()$date[1],"%Y-%m-%d") })
}

#Run the Shiny App to Display Webpage

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: I fixed the typo and used your two suggested lines.  This solution was unsuccessful as I am getting "Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"

Comment: It is because you use `stats::filter` which gives you a time series object. In that case `date` is in fourth column. I believe, you want to use `dplyr::filter` which gives you a data frame that you can subset with `$` operator.

Comment: it works because dplyr is already loaded in your environment. Try after restarting R

Comment: @krish once you add library('dplyr') to the top of your code it works.  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @HubertL for pointing that out. I have made the change to use `dplyr::filter` as @Michal Majka pointed out.

Comment: Could you please explain in your answer what was the real issue here?